# Python: How to spilt string in dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, key-value

I have the following JSON Data:

```
json_data = {"window_string": "X=-10 H=30 Y=20 W=40"}
```

How would I split the values to a list that is similar to this:

```
window_string = ["X = -10", "Y = 20", "W=40"]
```

Comment: That's not json data, that's a dict.

Comment: Why did the `H=30` disappear?

Comment: also why are some values formatted with a space

Answer (score 2):

```
json_data = {"window_string": "X=-10 H=30 Y=20 W=40"}
print(json_data["window_string"].split())    #Use str.split()
```

**Output:**

```
['X=-10', 'H=30', 'Y=20', 'W=40']
```

Answer (score 1):

`split()` function takes a string and splits it in list of strings, where every item in that splitted list is a word in the original string. Since `json_data['window_string']` has 4 words that every word is one item in the output list, it works just fine:

```
json_data = {'window_string': 'X=-10 H=30 Y=20 W=40'}
window_string = json_data['window_string'].split()
```